Windows 7 Not Booting after installing Ubuntu 22.04 alongside it
Windows 7 doesn't boot after dual booting with Ubuntu 22.04 on my HP Probook 450 G2. The boot mode is UEFI without CSM and in Legacy (MBR) mode it doesn't boot at all.
Windows Boot Manager gave me an error that winload.exe was missing or corrupt. I swapped that file for another that I found (and I also swapped the bootmgr(.efi) files, which didn't make any difference). Now it says that the digital signature of winload.exe is invalid. When I try to disable driver signature enforcement (via the F8 options menu), I get a BSOD (picture attached).
I really don't want to reinstall Windows, but if I have to, I can remove Ubuntu. I've also tried yannubuntu's Boot-Repair disk, but without success.
Note: I can still boot the HP recovery partition, but I am not sure exactly what it does and I don't want to risk making the whole situation even worse.
Here's the part about the Windows partitions of the diagnostic file from Boot-Repair:
sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda2 has 
                       739505712 sectors, but according to the info from 
                       fdisk, it has 739506175 sectors.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda3 has 
                       61044168 sectors, but according to the info from 
                       fdisk, it has 61044735 sectors.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /boot/bcd

Windows BSOD image:


Is Ubuntu installed?

Better to post link to boot-repair report so we could see the whole thing. From this snippets you provided diagnostic is impossible.

Here is a link to the files https://www.clechner.at/Boot-Info.zip

@DavidDE    Yes,it is installed.

Why a zip file? I know I will not take the time to unzip it and most others will not either.

Because I included the file before the repair and after the repair.
